# .net WPF and SQL Server CE crashing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sql-server-ce

I have an application in .net WPF that crashes randomly giving me the following errors:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x88980406 at
>   System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.Channel.SyncFlush() at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.UpdateWindowSettings(Boolean
>   enableRenderTarget, Nullable`1 channelSet) at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.UpdateWindowPos(IntPtr lParam) at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(WindowMessage msg,
>   IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>
> Not enough storage is available to complete this operation. at
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.ProcessResults(Int32 hr) at
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.Open(Boolean silent) at
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.Open() at
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean
>   openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection
>   originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation,
>   Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) OuterException The underlying
>   provider failed on Open. at
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean
>   openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection
>   originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation,
>   Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) at
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection() at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption)

Typically I get a number of the first error for a couple hours before I get the second repeatedly. It freeze up the whole application but when I get in to check after he customer calls me there is still a decent amount of memory left of the system. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are running out of disk space?. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978736.aspx

Comment: How is the customer running your app? Under a Standard or restricted account? SQL CE runs under the user's account and may have drive space restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Virus scanner? If you use SQL CE 4.0 SP1, you can add Open retry logic to your connection string